# Why does Django not find these urls, allthough the regex matches?

Tags: python, regex, django

In the python docs for regex there is the description of what the "." does:

> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.

For a project i do in Django i set up this regex:

```
url(r'^accounts/confirm/(.+)$', confirm,name='confirmation_view')
```

For all i understand, this should match any url that starts with 'accounts/confirm/', then followed by any number of arbitrary characters. These arbitrary characters are then passed to the function "confirm" as parameter. So far, so good.

So this regex should match

```
accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/
```

just as well as

```
accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e-048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/
```

and

```
accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e=048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/
```

and

```
accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e%20048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/
```

That, at least, was what i thought it would do. But it doesn't, it matches only the first one. Django keeps returning me a 404 on the other ones. Which i do not understand, because the (.+) part of the expression should mean "match one ore more of any character except a newline".

**edit:**
As the comments and answers proved, i got the regex right. So this is now a question about: why is Django not returning the correct view, but a 404. Is it doing some stuff to the url before passing it to that regex?

Comment: That is odd.  I don't have any personal experience with python regex, but in Java or javascript, it would work like that.  If . doesn't match anything, it's a newline character.

Comment: You don't, normally this regex should match your expectations. And the standard `re` module confirms this.

Comment: Ok, then it probably has to be some processing Django is doing to the url. I'll change my question accordingly.

Comment: I suspect that the url may do something on the string before passing to the confirm, such as adding new line

Comment: Logic dictates that if you remove all probable reasons, you're only left with the improbable reasons.  Better to verify that that's really the data you're dealing with.

Comment: @hwlau: My suspicion is more about escaping than about adding newlines

Comment: @marue, it would only fail if the string did not start with accounts/confirm/ and a non-newline character of any kind.  URL's don't contain newline characters unless they're escaped newline characters.

Comment: @Neil: there is no newline character. The non-working urls are exactly the same as the first one, i just inserted some special characters manually.

Comment: @marue Will it work if you change the regex to '^accounts/confirm/' ?

Comment: If the regex is correct then you should start a new question, showing your view code.

Comment: @ignacio: Django doesn't even direct to the view, but only shows a 404 page. The view code is never executed, as far as i know. Setting a breakpoint right in the first line of the view function confirms this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick test confirms this should work:

```
>>>import re
>>>test = ["accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/", "accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e-048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/", "accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e=048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/", "accounts/confirm/fb75c6529af9246e4e%20048d8a4298882909dc03ee0/"]
>>>all([re.match(r'^accounts/confirm/(.+)$', item) for item in test])
True
```

This will return false on any non matches:

```
>>>test.append("something else")
>>>all([re.match(r'^accounts/confirm/(.+)$', item) for item in test])
False
```

The problem must be elsewhere.